# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, iis-7, windows-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

hi everyone and thanks reading my serious issue with ASP.Net which kill all my time these days, I googled and test every thing but don't succeed.
I have written a website using `VS2010Express` it works nice in localhost but when I copy source codes to a **shared host** I got this error:

`HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error . The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

```
Module  AspNetInitializationExceptionModule
Handler PageHandlerFactory-Integrated
Error Code  0x00000000
```

More detailed info of my project:

1. I used entity-framework 4.4.20627.0
2. using .net 4

this is my web.config i think maybe there is something wrong:

**Edit:** Removed web.config contents!

and this is packages.config :

**Edit:** Removed packages.config contents!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally After 2 days googling and Stackoverflowing! I found the answer in my host documents. My **shared Host (server)** supports multiple languages like Php, Perl and also various version of Asp. So the problem was that my host admin had set **default Extension** to Asp.net 2 and mine was Asp.net 4 .

As my host panel was **WebsitePanel®** I followed these steps to change default Language:

1. Login to **WebsitePanel®**
2. Click "Web" icon -> "Web Sites"
3. Select my website name -> www.blabla.com
4. Click "Extensions" tab then change Asp.net2 to Asp.net4(Integrated)
5. Click "Update" button.
6. Finished! Now every thing is Ok.

Hope to be useful for others and save your time.